# Copying and pasting text requiring html entities

Tags: html, special-characters, dreamweaver

I want to copy and paste content from Outlook messages into DreamWeaver but a lot of autoformating messes things up. For example I copied "coming soon..." and the "..." was displayed correctly in DreamWeaver but actually had to be `&hellip;`

Can I:

1. Get DreamWeaver to automatically convert the pasted text into proper html entities
2. have DreamWeaver display incorrectly if it wouldn't display correctly in a web browser.

I'm working a lot with French characters.

**Alternatively** is there a way to force Outlook to display things normally?

Comment: This thread looks promising http://forums.adobe.com/thread/643635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your document encoding to 'Western European' instead of eg. UTF-8. (`Modify -> Page properties -> Title/Encoding`. Whenever you paste a special character in Design view, Dreamweaver will automatically convert it to the correct HTML enity - eg. … will be converted to `&hellip;`
2. I'm afraid that's not really possible - in many cases a web browser will render the special characters correctly, even without HTML-encoding - all depends on your specific setup.

Answer (score 0):

A tool such as http://centricle.com/tools/html-entities/ may be able to help you.  It will encode or decode HTML entities from the text you provide.